# Image doesn't follow the page flow and covers ul

Tags: html, css

When I try to add an image to the bottom of a page, after an `<ul>`, the image stacks up to this list, not following the flow of the page.

The actual result:
[image: how the page displays the problem]

The intended result:
[image: how it should be]

with image at the bottom

My code:

```css
* {
  Font-family: Georgia;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair display";
  color: rgba(0,102,255,0.7);
  background-color: rgba(120, 249, 17, 0.3);
  word-spacing: 0.3 em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p,ul,ol {
  color: DarkSlateGrey;
  line-height: 1.8em;;
  word-spacing: 0.3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
a { font-style: italic;
}
.header {
 /*background: url("https://www.newyorkspaces.com/upload10/122775/Zebide-Emerald-City-MLB308WALL---Copy.jpg") repeat-x    center center;*/
 background-size: contain;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#369, #6CC);
 border-style: solid;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 position: static;
 z-index: 1000;
}
.menu {
 word-spacing: 5em;
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul {
 width: 80%;
 margin: auto;
 height: 30px;
}
#homepage-menu ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline;
 border: 1px solid rgba(204,102,102,1);
 background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.2);
 font-size: 18px;
 width:90%;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
.content {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-style: 1px solid rgba(204,204,204,1);
 background-color: rgba(102,102,102,0.07);
 width: 50%;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 10px;
 /*position: relative;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px; */
 z-index: 999;
 text-align:justify;
}
.link {
 width:50%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.image {
 height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0px auto;3
}
```

```html
<div>

<p>So far I have learned the following things:</p>

<ul>
  <li>Create a boilerplate in HTML</li>
  <li>Heading and title</li>
  <li>Create a paragraph</li>
  <li>Create Un-oredered and Ordered Lists (UL & OL)</li>
  <li>Insert a link to a page (Hyperlink)</li>
  <li>Insert Image on your page</li>
  <li>Insert ALT description for unpaired people</li>
  <li>Link image to a hyperlink</li>
  <li>Insert a BREAK onto my page</li>
  <li>W3C Style standard</li>
  <li>Insert non visible comment</li>
  <li>How to set up HTML link to CSS page(style page)</li>
  <li>Styling FONTS (font-family, font-style, font size, font weight, serif-sans-serif,)</li>
  <li>SPACING Lines, words and letters with PX - eM - </li>
  <li>Text TRANSFORM and Text ALIGN</li>
  </ul>
</div>   
   <img class="bowie" src="http://esq.h-cdn.co/assets/16/02/980x490/landscape-1452522826-david-bowie-5.jpg"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS please.

Comment: You can find the CSS code at the top of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because your have a fixed height for `ul` in your CSS code.

```
height: 30px;
```

removing the height will fix the problem.

I also added

```
img {max-width:100; height: auto}
```

to make images responsive.

```css
* {
  Font-family: Georgia;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Playfair display";
  color: rgba(0, 102, 255, 0.7);
  background-color: rgba(120, 249, 17, 0.3);
  word-spacing: 0.3em;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.7em;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

p,
ul,
ol {
  color: DarkSlateGrey;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  word-spacing: 0.3em;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

a {
  font-style: italic;
}

.header {
  /*background: url("https://www.newyorkspaces.com/upload10/122775/Zebide-Emerald-City-MLB308WALL---Copy.jpg") repeat-x    center center;*/
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#369, #6CC);
  border-style: solid;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: static;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.menu {
  word-spacing: 5em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

ul {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

#homepage-menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 102, 102, 1);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.content {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1);
  background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.07);
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 10px;
  /*position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px; */
  z-index: 999;
  text-align: justify;
}

.link {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.image {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <p>So far I have learned the following things:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Create a boilerplate in HTML</li>
    <li>Heading and title</li>
    <li>Create a paragraph</li>
    <li>Create Un-oredered and Ordered Lists (UL & OL)</li>
    <li>Insert a link to a page (Hyperlink)</li>
    <li>Insert Image on your page</li>
    <li>Insert ALT description for unpaired people</li>
    <li>Link image to a hyperlink</li>
    <li>Insert a BREAK onto my page</li>
    <li>W3C Style standard</li>
    <li>Insert non visible comment</li>
    <li>How to set up HTML link to CSS page(style page)</li>
    <li>Styling FONTS (font-family, font-style, font size, font weight, serif-sans-serif,)</li>
    <li>SPACING Lines, words and letters with PX - eM - </li>
    <li>Text TRANSFORM and Text ALIGN</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<img class="bowie" src="http://esq.h-cdn.co/assets/16/02/980x490/landscape-1452522826-david-bowie-5.jpg" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much... sorted with your help.

Comment: Can you please tell me the reason it was appearing as a normal ul without the picture and it takes the height of 30px when I finally try to add the image at the bottom?

Comment: @Karma-code Awesome, thank you! The reason it was displaying "normally" is because the `height` limit was on the `ul` element. You had not declared that if the items inside the `ul` element exceeded it's height then the browser should add a scroll bar.  I have set up a few examples to demonstrate the point. (1)

Comment: [Example #1](https://jsfiddle.net/y9ahk0v2/) No `height` limit on `ul`. I added a red background to the `ul` element so you can easily see it.

Comment: [Example #2](https://jsfiddle.net/4d01g9u6/) I gave the `ul` element a red background like before and no `height` limit . I also gave `li` inside the `ul` a green background.

Comment: [Example #3](https://jsfiddle.net/kz293nsf/) Same as #2 except `ul` now has a fixed height. Notice how the red background stops at `30px` which is the defined height.

Comment: [Example #4](https://jsfiddle.net/n8qs9m0u/) in this example I increased the `ul` height to `100px` for the sake of this demo, but I also told the browser to add a scroll bar if the items inside the `ul` exceed its height using `overflow-y:auto` In this example, scrolling on the `ul` item will scroll the element instead of the entire window.

Comment: Hope that explains everything.

Comment: That was a great lesson! Now I also recall the overflow declaration!

Comment: @Karma-code I'm glad you found the information useful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: 30px;` from ul in your css